# Sketch the region enclosed by $y= \sqrt{x}$, $y=0$, $x=4$ and calculate its area

Tags: calculus

I do not understand how this would work to find the area. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you attempted thus far? Are you aware on how to approach the problem?

Comment: You do not understand how *what?* would work to find the area?

Comment: Integrals are useful here.  Have you seen any descriptions of the geometric interpretation of the integral $\int\limits_a^bf(x)dx$?  Can you describe your problem as an integral of some appropriate $f(x)$ with some appropriate limits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sketch the graph on paper. The required area is area under curve of $\sqrt{x}$ from $x=0$ to $x=4$.

$$\int_{0}^{4} \sqrt{x} dx = \frac{2}{3} \left(4^{3/2}-0^{3/2}\right) = \frac{16}{3}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Won't that simply be $$\int _{0}^4 \sqrt x.  dx=?$$

Comment: How is that a "hint"?

Comment: @JMoravitz hahahh that's funny. I guess perhaps as a *strong hint*, you should say $$\int_0^4\sqrt{x} \ \text{d}x = \ ?$$

Comment: The question was easy so I could not think anything else which could provide a hint to this question. If I have to it would be simply "use integrals"

Comment: As you say brothers.

Comment: Man, you guys have a good sense of humour :)

Comment: @user477343  Thats the reason why I say that mathlovers can also be humorous

Comment: I wish I could vote, but I have to wait $20$ hours hahah

Comment: @user477343    Is the universe going to expand at a rate much faster after 20 hours as compared to present?  No one even bothered to tell me about it.

Comment: XD that's hilarious

Comment: @user477343 Glad you enjoyed the experience of MSE happiness and fun.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you can sketch the graph.

Note that there are two different ways to find the area.

One way which is probably easier, is to avoid the square root and integrate in y direction.

Area =$ \int\limits_0^2(4-y^2)dy$= $16/3$

The other way is to integrate in x direction and remember to change your limits of integration to $0$ and $4$

Comment: Are you sure the answer must be 128/3

Comment: Now whom are you pointing the word "he" towards.

Comment: I think in the upper limit it should be 2 while instead of (16-y²)  it should have been (4-y²)

Comment: The correct answer is 16/3 Ifixed my error.